# Breadcrumb on click of sap.m.Tree list item and expand collapse the tree on click of the breadcrumb

Tags: sapui5

I implemented the sap.m.Tree using below code

```
<Tree busyIndicatorDelay="0"
                        id="TreeList" select="onToggleOpenState" mode="SingleSelectMaster"
                         items="{treeModel>/}">
                        <StandardTreeItem title="{treeModel>Description}" icon="sap-icon://attachment-e-pub" />
</Tree>
```

[image: Tree looks likes as below image]

Let's assume user clicks on 3.1.1.3 then I will get below breadcrumb bar

> 3 / 3.1 / 3.1.1 / 3.1.1.3

I have maintained nodeId as (parent~child~child~child....) to achieve breadcrumb
and below is the code for the same

```
onToggleOpenState: function(oEvent){
          var sPath = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContextPath();
          var sNodeDesc = this._oView.getModel("treeModel").getProperty(sPath).NodeId;
          var aBreadCum = sNodeDesc.split("~");
          var oBreadCrumb = this._oView.byId("breadCrumb");
          oBreadCrumb.removeAllLinks();                     
          for(var i = 0; i < aBreadCum.length; i++){
            if(i === (aBreadCum.length - 1)) {
              oBreadCrumb.setCurrentLocationText(aBreadCum[i]);
            }
            else{                  
              var oCrumbRoot = new sap.m.Link({
                text: aBreadCum[i],
                press: [this._crumbClick, this]                   
            });               
            oBreadCrumb.addLink(oCrumbRoot);
            }
          }
        },

        _crumbClick: function (oEvent, data) {

      },
```

I don't feel it's an appropriate way to implement the same as someone change the id (NodeId) pattern in the backend, everything will break. so is there any alternative way to do the same?

Further, if the user clicks on "3.1" in above breadcrumb, then tree should be expanded till the level 3.1 and one immediate level (all other branches should be collapsed.) like below image

[image: Tree expand on breadcrumb click]

any idea how to achieve this?